# Adding Folders using CSOM is raising this error "System.ArgumentException: 'The 'parameters.LeafName' argument is invalid.'"

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have the following CSOM inside my remote event receiver for SharePoint online site:-

```
ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
listItemCreationInformation.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
listItemCreationInformation.LeafName = *********************
List templatelsit = context.Web.GetList(webrelativeurl + "/" + template["TemplateListUrl"]);
ListItem listItem2 = templatelsit.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);
```

but on some folders such as when my `listItemCreationInformation` = `/123456 International Holdings 1234567 (in Liquidation)/Investment/Portfolio Management/Strategy/Asset management initial strategy` i am getting this error:-

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The 'parameters.LeafName' argument is invalid.'
```

is this because of the length of the folder path? if so, then what is the maximum length i can have? keeping in mind if i try to add the path using the UI i can add this folder `/123456 International Holdings 1234567 (in Liquidation)/Investment/Portfolio Management/Strategy/Asset management initial strategy` and even more sub-folders...

Comment: What is the object `listItemCreationInformation2`? You don't show the initialization of that object in your code.

Comment: @TrevorSeward sorry i updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create nested folders at one go. I would suggest to create the top level folder first and then create the sub folder under it, then move on to the next level ...

You can find a useful implementation of creating nested folders [in this link](https://cassy.be/site/sharepoint-csom-created-nested-folder-structure-ensure-folder-code-sample/). You can modify it to feed a whole path of your target folder and then split the input by '/' character and navigate down by creating each folder on your path.

Like if your path is /A/B/C/D then you can feed '/A/B/C/D' string to your method, split by '/' to get array of folder names ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] and the start by creating folder 'A'. then folder 'B' underneath and so on.

I have tried to create something for your need based on the above example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Will ensure nested folder creation if folders in folderPath don't exist.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ctx">Loaded SharePoint Client Context</param>
/// <param name="list">Document Library SharePoint List Object</param>
/// <param name="fullFolderPath">Complete folder path ParentFolder/ChildFolder1/ChildFolder2/...</param>
/// <returns>Last ChildFolder as target</returns>
private static Folder EnsureAndGetTargetFolder(ClientContext ctx, List list, string fullFolderPath)
{
    Folder returnFolder = null;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fullFolderPath))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fullFolderPath));
    }

    string[] folderPath = fullFolderPath.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (folderPath != null && folderPath.Length > 0)
    {
        Web web = ctx.Web;
        Folder currentFolder = list.RootFolder;
        ctx.Load(web, t => t.Url);
        ctx.Load(currentFolder);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        if(currentFolder.ServerObjectIsNull == null || currentFolder.ServerObjectIsNull.HasValue == false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Root folder not loaded.");
        }

        foreach (string folderName in folderPath)
        {
            FolderCollection folders = currentFolder.Folders;
            ctx.Load(folders);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            if (folders.ServerObjectIsNull == null || folders.ServerObjectIsNull.HasValue == false)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to load folders.");
            }

            bool folderFound = false;
            foreach (Folder existingFolder in folders)
            {
                if (existingFolder.Name.Equals(folderName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    folderFound = true;
                    currentFolder = existingFolder;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!folderFound)
            {
                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation
                {
                    UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder,
                    LeafName = folderName,
                    FolderUrl = currentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
                };

                ListItem folderItemCreated = list.AddItem(itemCreationInfo);
                folderItemCreated.Update();
                ctx.Load(folderItemCreated, f => f.Folder);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                currentFolder = folderItemCreated.Folder;
            }
        }

        returnFolder = currentFolder;
    }

    return returnFolder;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.